# Android Image gridview using date header

Tags: android, gridview, image-gallery

I am trying to do a image gallery which is going to show images ordered by date 
i have found custom gallery code and the code is working well

can anybody help me sort the images by date

```
Date---
Img1 Img2 Img3
Date---
Img1 Img2 Img3

public class MyGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();

        final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
        selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                int cnt = 0;
                String selectImages = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        //selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrPath[i]);

                        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goProDialogImage);

                        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
                        dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
                if (cnt == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select at least one image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int id = v.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
                            "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }
}
```

Kindly kelp me to find a better solution

Comment: try this final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

Comment: https://github.com/guoGavin/Andorid-StickyHeaderGridView - verygood work it resolved my issue

Comment: I am not able to change sticky header with the above example is it possible to change it?